# How to run my php code in every X minute?

Tags: php, ajax

i try to make a "status monitor" for our small network. After the page was load i make a ping for every IP which i addedd. Its, ok. But i would like to do this ping in every X minute, without reload my hole page.

I can make it if i reload the page with header refresh, but i would like to do this witout reload.

I think i have to do this with AJAX?, But i dont know how..

Thank you

Comment: Hire a monkey and tell it to press F5 every few minutes.

Comment: @rochal the monkey will refresh the whole page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do here, but this [quick tutorial](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/call-php-ajax-every-second-jquery.html) shows you how to call a php file every second and update a dib block with the results. It is quick and simple using jquery.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest you have a look at [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) or something similar:

1) you don't need to have a web page constantly open to detect problems

2) it can automatically verify and escalate issues

3) there are lots of probes available out of the box which can be used to measure all sorts of things - not just ping times

4) responding to a ping is not the same thing as working

5) it automatically collates stats to identify patterns of issues

6) it also provides SLA type reporting

7) Nagios is simple enough that even I can understand it

8) its what I chose after a lot of work researching a replacement for a system similar to you are suggesting.

HTH

C.

Answer (score 2):

If it is entire code of page i suggest setting up a cron job

and if you want to use ajax ( ie jquery ajax there is a plugin called jquery timer) use it send a ajax request to the page with code you want to run.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers
check this out

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at some of the "other-way-around" approaches, such as COMET, [here](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start) is an interesting article covering basic usage with PHP.

This would put the implementation of "ping" in your server instead of the client.

You could for instance instead of setting a fixed interval push out updates at will. Meaning you would get almost realtime status notifications instead of the fixed interval updates.

> In web development, Comet is a
>   neologism to describe a web
>   application model in which a long-held
>   HTTP request allows a web server to
>   push data to a browser, without the
>   browser explicitly requesting it.
>   Comet is an umbrella term for multiple
>   techniques for achieving this
>   interaction. All these methods rely on
>   features included by default in
>   browsers, such as JavaScript, rather
>   than on non-default plugins.

[COMET (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try a cron?

Comment: I have already posted that, post it if you have something new